# Sort Order by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2017

I have table like this:

```
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| ID | Name | sortorder | overridesortorder |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1  | kkkk | 4         | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2  | yyyy | 3         | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 3  | zzzz | 2         | 4                 |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 4  | gggg | 1         | 3                 |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 5  | bbbb | null      | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 6  | aaaa | null      | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
```

I need to display the order like below, sorting the table with above two sort order columns (**if both values are null then sort with Name column**) and Get the max value from two columns then sort it.:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| ID | Name  | sortorder | overridesortorder |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1  | kkkk  | **4**     | null              |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 3  | zzzz  | 2         | **4**             |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2  | yyyy  | **3**     | null              |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 4  | gggg  | 1         | **3**             |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------------+
| 6  | bbbb  | null      | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| 5  | aaaa  | null      | null              |
+----+------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Your expected output is inconsistent.  In some cases you sort ascending by the name, in other cases descending.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for this

```
declare @t table(
    ID int
    , Name varchar(100)
    , sortorder int
    , overridesortorder int
)
insert into @t
values 
    (1, 'kkkk', 4, null)
    , (2, 'yyyy', 3, null)
    , (3, 'zzzz', 2, 4)
    , (4, 'gggg', 1, 3)
    , (5, 'bbbb', null, null)
    , (6, 'aaaa', null, null)

select
    *
from
    @t
order by coalesce(case when isnull(sortorder, 0) > isnull(overridesortorder, 0) then sortorder else overridesortorder end, -2147483648) desc, Id, Name
```

Output

```
ID  Name    sortorder  overridesortorder 
----------------------------------------
1   kkkk    4          NULL
3   zzzz    2          4
2   yyyy    3          NULL
4   gggg    1          3
5   bbbb    NULL       NULL
6   aaaa    NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly, `overridesortorder` column simply overrides `sortorder` column. You can use `COALESCE` to return the first non-null value and this is essential when both columns are null to return zero.

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(overridesortorder, sortorder, 0) DESC, 
         ISNULL(sortorder, 0) DESC,
         Name
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a11e8/1).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ?

```
select * 
from table
order by coalesce(overridesortorder, sortorder) desc, overridesortorder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT  *
        ,(CASE WHEN ISNULL(sortorder,0) > ISNULL(overridesortorder,0)
          THEN ISNULL(sortorder,0) 
          ELSE ISNULL(overridesortorder,0) END) AS FinalSortOrder
FROM    YourTable
ORDER BY FinalSortOrder DESC
        ,sortorder DESC
        ,overridesortorder DESC
        ,Name DESC
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c80a/12)